# Conditional Probability problem given 5 cards where 3 are black and the other two are red

Tags: probability, statistics

If I am given $5$ cards, where three of the cards are black and they are numbered 1, 2, 3. The other two cards are red and they are numbered 1, 2. I pick two random cards.

I determined that the probability that both cards are red is $2/5 \cdot 1/4 = 1/10$ since they are not being replaced.

What would be the probability that both cards are red if we know that at least one of them is red?

What about if both cards are red if we know that one of them is red card number 1?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Have you tried answering the two questions you asked yourself?  Please show your work and explain where are you stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You are correct in the first part.  For the others, use the definition of conditional probability.